# Internet Explorer 8 - this website has been reported as unsafe

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

All my websites are written in asp.net. All are same code based and use telerik components and google analytics.

Now some of them are displayed as "this website has been reported as unsafe" in internet explorer 8.

Any suggestion? Appreciate your comments!

Comment: Could you show me how to accept it? I don't know how.

Comment: @winmyan You just have to click the checkmark beside the answer you think is best - if your question has been answered. You can see all your questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/296861/winmyan. If someone has posted an acceptable answer, you should click the checkmark beside their answer.

Comment: Thanks Radu, I accpeted the answer.

Comment: I removed a number of "me too" posts that weren't really *answers*, but do support the question. Rest assured:  you were not alone in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny.  Just checked my site again and no longer getting the error.  It was specific to pages with the RadMenu for sure.  Tried navigating to other pages with other Telerik controls and even those with no Telerik controls (including those with Analytics code) and all were fine.  Looks like a mess up from our friends at Microsoft.

Comment: My experience is the same. The problem is cleared up now. The whole site has a RadMenu control for navigation, and the whole site was blacklisted.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a Microsoft issue. Some of our customer facing web sites have been experiencing the same issue today. Our web team is working with Microsoft to resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes, it happens today. If you have some tips from microsoft, please share us.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe this has to do with the technology necessarily. You have been either manually reported or you have an exposed vulnerability on your site.

Comment: Dustin is right. If there is a link on the page that says "why has this been flagged as unsafe?" or something to that effect, click it and it will show why, obviously. In my experience it has been an issue with <script> tags to malicious sites that have been placed in some of the files on the server.

Comment: Dustin & Kobby, I don't agree with you on that. All my sites are suddenly working fine now (within a couple of hour). Per other comments, I think something to do with Telerik compontent and Microsoft.

Comment: It may be, however there is something unsafe being flagged and reported. Whatever the cause the result is the error you are encountering. I wanted to inform that the error is not the root and only a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here, websites are using Telerik Rad Menu! Now everything seems fine.

As much as I think Rad Controls are an abomination, i wouldn' flag them as unsafe! :)

Comment: MS acknowledged the issue and has fixed it:  http://twitter.com/#!/MicrosoftHelps